# nmap -sT 192.168.8.0/24 is being very slow

Tags: nmap

I started learning nmap but I ran into a big problem. I was following some youtube tutorials and the command `nmap -sT 192.168.8.0/24` took over 27 minutes while I saw that for many it took around 2 seconds. So what is the reason for so slow speed?

Comment: Increase the level of verbosity when running the command. You can also try without DNS resolution: add the `-n` option.

Comment: Try adding the -T4 flag

Comment: Have you tried to solve this yourself? https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+speed+up+nmap+scan

Comment: Are you per chance running this inside a VM?

Comment: What OS are you running? Wired or wireless? Number of hosts within that IP range? Many things can affect the speed of an `-sT` scan. Old/cheap WiFi adapters for example.

Comment: So `-n` and `-T4` didn't speed it up. I am not doing it in VM, but what I have found strange is this: `Stats: 0:00:03 elapsed; 251 hosts completed (4 up), 4 undergoing Connect Scan
Connect Scan Timing: About 0.06% done` It complete most of host in moment but is having problem with last 4.

Comment: Forget to say. Running Windows 10. For now there are 4 up hosts in network, and I am using `Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM` this is 1000Mb, and I am connected using cable.